# Alfresco CMIS service to index document

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I have uploaded document to Alfresco using Apache Chemistry php client. The documents is uploaded successfully but (I think it is not indexed), content based search is not working on this document. whereas If I upload the same document from alfresco share it is also indexed and content based search works on it. Kindly tell me about cmis service to index document or propose me some solution for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should just work - any errors in the logs?

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr for your response.  are you talking about alfresco.log ? I  have checked it. there is not any error. but it is not working.

Comment: Does the document library preview work? Any strange permissions applied to it?

Comment: No, I have not applied any permission. I am just using https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/phpclient/  to create file and using cmis url http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom on alfresco version 5. can you tell me how can I check document library preview ?

Comment: Just upload the file via CMIS, then go to that node in Share and call the document details page up and check the preview

Comment: Previously I was using  this url  http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/s/cmis on alfresco 4.2 and it was showing  preview. but I shift on alfresco 5 and on it with this url http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom it is not showing preview. however the file is ok. I can download and see its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to figure out issue with Apache chemistry php client. so I shifted to java version i.e. **alfresco-api-examples**. link https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-api-java-examples and following its **CmisCreateDocumentExample** the file is now successfully uploaded and indexed.